# bypass permission error in python while creating file in drive c://

Tags: permissions, python, file-permissions

how can bypass permission error while creating or writing data in python

```
 def os_commands():  # permission error
        string = '#       ::2             localhostttttttttt'
        with open(r'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', 'r+') as h:
        hosts = h.write(string)
```

while running this code give me this Error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'
```

how can I bypass this Error in windows 10

Comment: You may need to run your python code as an administrator. That directory will be protected by the operating system.

Comment: If just any account could edit the hosts file, it would be VERY bad.  Malware would be even worse than it already is.